# Get string between two identifiers on multiple lines with a line by line read

Tags: python, string, optimization, text

I have a huge text file which I need to read line by line for memory optimization.
I would like to get the string within two identifiers, as an example here between the identifiers '{' and '}':

```
input:
"
not this line
not this line
Pattern 'pattern' {
get this line 
get this line 
}
not this line
not this line
"

the output would be a string "get this line get this line "
```

There can be some other identifiers ('{', '}', '[', ...) inside the string but I need matching ones. Ex: `Pattern { something else {...} }` would get `something else {...}` (the englobed {...} is inside the string)

I have written a simple counter like this but it is quite slow. I was looking at a faster way of doing this.

```
currentString = ""
counter = 0

def GetStringBetweenIdentifiers(string, identifierA, identifierB):
    global currentString, counter

    for i in string:
        if (i == identifierB):
            counter -= 1
        
        if(counter > 0):
            currentString += i
            
        if(i == identifierA):
            counter += 1
            
    if(counter==0):
        string = currentString
        currentString = ""
        return string
    return ""


with open(filePath) as read_obj:
        for num, line in enumerate(read_obj, 1):
            String = GetStringBetweenIdentifiers(line, '{', '}')
            if (String != ""):
                "Do something with the string"
```

To add some examples, there can be identifiers in the middle of the line, for example:

```
input:
"
not this line
not this line
Pattern 'pattern' { I want this 
get this line { something here }
get this line 
also this part } not this part
not this line
not this line
"

the output would be a string " I want this get this line { something here } get this line also this part"
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: I think you need to contrive more sample input and output data for us to properly understand this

Comment: I suspect the bottleneck here is file I/O, and not processing. Have you [profiled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) your code to see which parts take the longest to run?

Comment: Pranav Hosangadi - Yes it is this function (GetStringBetweenIdentifiers) that is taking the most time.

Comment: Albert Winestein - Ok, I'll try to add more relevant examples.

Comment: One suggestion I have is to make `currentString` a _list_ instead of a string, append all the lines to that list, and join it into a single string before returning (since appending to a string more expensive than appending to a list).

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Amazing how much it has got faster with just this! I did not know string append was so slow! Thanks for the tip

Comment: Great! The reason is that strings are immutable, so when you append to a string you basically create a _whole new string_ that contains the old one plus the added part, which means the contents need to be copied to the new string. Lists don't have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing can be very tricky due to ambiguous sequences. For example... Let's say that the start of a sequence of interest is '{' and the end is '}'. Now imagine that you've observed a start sentinel then, before you see an end marker, you see another start marker. What do you do then?

Anyway, here's something that will work in the perfect world (which doesn't really exist but it might give some ideas).

My input file looks like this:

```
not this line
not this line
Pattern 'pattern' { I want this
get this line { something here }
get this line
also this part } not this part
not this line
not this line
```

...and the code like this...

```
START = '{'
END = '}'

capture = 0
data = []
section = []
with open('foo.txt') as txt:
    while (c := txt.read(1)):
        if c == START:
            if (capture := capture + 1) > 1:
                section.append(c)
        elif c == END:
            if (capture := capture - 1) < 0:
                print('ERROR: unable to process (too many end tags)')
                break
            if capture:
                section.append(c)
            elif section:
                data.append(section)
                section = []
        elif capture and c not in '\r\n':
            section.append(c)
for section in data:
    print(''.join(section))
```

...and this output....

```
I want this get this line { something here }get this line also this part
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think there might be a problem if there are multiple identifiers inside one another. I edit the question for more clarification. Sorry I did not explain this enough!

Comment: @alexandresecond That's exactly the kind of issue that I was highlighting at the start of my answer. I'll provide an edit shortly

Comment: @alexandresecond Edited to suit your revised requirements. I would expect this to be very efficient. Let me know if it isn't

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it tomorrow and update you about it!

Comment: Yup that works great, it is quite fast! In fact it is comparable to my solution replacing the currentString variable into a list. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to the world of `regex`.  It's quirky, but highly effective.  This works for your situation, if in the lines you read there is only one capture-able sequence, which may contain sub sequences that might also be captured, as you show in your example.  It will fail if there are independent sequences within the same input string, as it will capture the "outer most" subsequence that it finds.  It would be a little more work to have it handle this case.  (As they say, an exercise left to the interested reader.)

Lots of good info in the python dox and this [website](https://regex101.com) is key for testing.

Aside:  You may also want to look into `grep` terminal command (not a python solution).  `grep` is highly effective at processing massive files and pulling out matches and it works seamlessly with `regex` also

Anyhow:

```
import re


with open('dummy_text.txt', 'r') as src:
    lines = src.readlines()

composite_string = ''.join(lines)

print('loaded and working with:\n')
print(composite_string)
print()

pattern = r'{((?s:.*))}'
results = re.search(pattern, composite_string)

print(f'I found: {results.group(1)}')
```

#### Produces:

```
loaded and working with:

not this line
not this line
Pattern 'pattern' {
get this line 
get {this} line 
}
not this line
not this line

I found: 
get this line 
get {this} line
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation for your regex?

Comment: I think for this to work I need to read my entire file and put all of it in memory right? This is not something I can do unfortunatelly. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Also regex is not a great solution when you have possibly nested delimiters that you need to count

Comment: I have tens of GB size files, that's why I wanted to read line by line to reduce memory budget. I don't know how grep would handle this? I am not so familiar with this. Anyway if possible I would like to keep this on Python since I will parse the file for readability.

Comment: @alexandresecond I guess I didn't get a complete understanding of your file-read strategy.  I thought you were reading in chunks of the file where you knew to look (which looks like your example code).  If you are truly reading lines of the file until you find an opening/closing delimiter, then this isn't a good approach, but `grep` likely is.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi.  If you cut & paste my regex onto the website linked, it breaks it down completely.  Basically a capture group between curly braces, that includes any char or space/newline char repeated.

Comment: Ok I know grep is very powerful! If I find it too slow on Python I'll try it. But if possible I would like to keep everything on Python since I already wrote the code for the parsing part.

Comment: I know what the regex means (although I didn't know that python's regex engine allows capturing group flag modifiers). Sure, I could go off-site for an explanation, but an answer should be self-contained, and an answer that explains _how_ and _why_ your regex works is more valuable to OP and the general community than an answer that says "Do this"

Comment: @PranavHosangadi.  Fair point, thank you!  So, this isn't a good fit for the read strategy.  I'll leave it up as a "thought piece."  :)  Not sure if `grep` can power through the line breaks either, so that may be a dead end as well.  :(